# Any good open source web service testing tools?

Tags: xml, soap

I m fairly new to SOAP based web services. I m looking for a good open source testing tool , that will help me automate regression testing.

I found webinject.

Was wondering , if there are any other tools.

thanks.

Comment: Ditto to SoapUI. Isn't webinject more for browser-based testing, as opposed to web services?

Answer (score 3):

Evaluate [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) as well

Comment: does it provide automated testing functionality ?

Answer (score 1):

eviware has a tool "SOAPUI" whit a Free version and a Eclipse-Plugin http://www.soapui.org/

This is a very good tool that can make complex test